# Is it possible to enable UPnP without going into Router web interface?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat, upnp

So I lost the password for my router, and I am living in a rural area, so contacting the ISP is a hassle. I was wondering if it is possible to enable UPnP option without accessing the router settings. (I need to enable it because my Nat is strict on most games I am playing. (like Gta online))

I have already tried forwarding specific ports via the control panel. But my nat is still strict.

Edit: My modem is Netlink. And I port forwarded by going to the sharing tab on the adapter settings properties.

Comment: Edited the post to add more info

Comment: when you say "via the control panel" do you mean on the router that you cannot login to? if not then those settings will likely have no affect. the port forwarding you need can only be configured on the router. but yes, it UPNP is not currently enabled, you will not be able to enable it without logging into the router.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the settings of the modem to add port forwarding (or a DMZ, etc.) you will need to access the modem's control panel.

If you look at the information package you received when you installed your service you may find the information there.

Unfortunately, if you do not have the username and password, and they are not printed bottom of the modem, you will need to get support from your ISP.